# asp.net mvc 2 Change redirection of unauthorized actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, unauthorized

Solution is called Portal which holds Areas/CMS/Login folder inside it. Login controller in CMS/Controllers is almost the same as AccountController in Portal solution. I customized Login and it works all fine except one thing: When I use `[Authorize]` filter and If user is not logged in than he is redirected to http://localhost:1177/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fCMS%2fArticle and I would like that redirection takes user to here:
http://localhost:1177/CMS/Login 
Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying that you have a specific log in for just CMS as well as a login for the website?

Comment: While project is in development I will have two logins, for final presentation I will create one user, delete login from portal and it will leave one user account and login/logoff (without possibility to register new users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web.config will probably contain a portion that looks like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

It is the loginUrl that defines where the AuthorizeAttribute redirects you to when the user is not authorized yet.  The return url that is passed into the action is what you can use to redirect the user back to once he is authorized.